# Problemas de selección ID con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

necesito el id del td que estoy subiendo un archivo, el tema que para capturar el id lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
$("input[type=file]").click(function(){

    if(materialID !=''){
            materialID = '';
        }

    $(".textos1").click(function(){

        materialID = '';
        materialID = $(".textos",this).val();
        console.log(materialID);        
     });




 });
```

donde textos1 es la clase el td (class='textos1')
y texto en la clase del input (class='textos')
también en el mismo td mando un input con el iD

```
"<input type='hidden' id='hiddenID'" + correMateriales2 + " value="+ID+" class='textos'>"
```

cuando selecciono el input en el DOM, si bien me toma el id y me lo muestra por consola, el problema es que cuando selecciono nuevamente
 el input, este me muestra el id, pero repetido en 1+ y asi sucesivamente, ejemplo
 primera vez que selecciono: 1
 segunda vez que selecciono: 13 13
 tercera vez que selecciono: 122 122 122

siendo el id cualquier numero, solo puse este de ejemplo

Comment: No entiendo. Si estás buscando obtener el id del td en el que se hace click, ¿por qué no usar `event.target.id`? Quizás ayudaría ver un ejemplo del HTML para terminar de entender.

Comment: Prueba con sacar el evento click que tienes dentro de otro evento click, luego revisa nuevamente

Comment: @Mariano disculpa estoy empezando en el tema, como funciona el event.target.id? me traeria el id de input type = 'hidden' ?

Comment: @elsa No. Te traería el id del elemento en el cual hiciste click. Por eso es que sería bueno [edit] la pregunta mostrando un ejemplo breve del HTML para contextualizar... Fijate el comentario de Irwing que explica por qué hay eventos duplicados.

Comment: @elsa Fijate que el click del .textos1, esta dentro de la otra función. Como te han comentado antes, haz dos funciones distintas, para poder obtener el resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el `id` de un elemento basta con hacer uso del evento o del propio elemento para obtenerlo.

```
$('input[type=hidden').on('click', function(ev) {
  let value = $(this).id;
  let sameValue = ev.target.id;
});
```

En este escenario, tanto `value` como `sameValue` tienen el mismo valor. En JavaScript toda acción es representada por un evento. El evento es pasado al `callback` que asocias a `X` suceso. En este caso, `ev` tendrá la información del suceso `click`. Puedes imprimirlo por consola para ver todas sus propiedades.

La interface [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) tiene la propiedad de sola lectura `target` el cual te devuelve el elemento del DOM que ha desencadenado el evento. Ya que todos los eventos heredan de ésta interface, en el evento `click` también puedes acceder a `target`. Una vez obtenido el elemento que ha desencadenado el evento, puedes acceder a sus propiedades. Como en tu caso es una caja de texto, puedes acceder a su propiedad `id` directamente.

> Los input `hidden` no responden a eventos producidos por el usuario por obvias razones. Solo se puede desencadenar eventos en ellos de forma **programática**.

Si quieres que al subir un archivo, quieras mandar también un identificador, entonces tu código debería ser:

```
$("input[type=file]").click(function() {
  if(materialID !=''){
    materialID = '';
  }
  // asumiendo que el td contiene
  // tanto el input file como el hidden
  materialID = $(this).find('.textos1').id;
});
```

Si estás usando `materialID` como variable global, te aconsejo pienses bien si es necesario. Si solo necesitas asociar un `id` a un a subida, `materialID` puede ser una variable local:

```
$("input[type=file]").click(function() {
  let materialID = $(this).find('.textos1').id;
});
```